# The use of the phrase "be good" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It was in the ninth episode of the sixth season of *Friends*. It in this [video](https://youtu.be/i5YckMkwmm4). It's at 1 minute and 31 seconds. Here is the context:

> Monica: Whoa whoa whoa! Where’re you goin’?
>
> Ross: Oh, oh, we did say we’d stop by this little thing Joey’s
>   roommate is having.
>
> Monica: Oh, Janine, the really hot dancer girl?
>
> Ross: Some would say she’s attractive, yes.
>
> Phoebe: And who else is going to be there?
>
> Joey: Uh, some of her friends, yeah.
>
> Rachel: Her dancer friends?
>
> Joey: (frustrated) Yes, all right? All of her hot dancer friends are
>   gonna be there and they’re gonna be, be drinkin’ and dancin, and we
>   really wanna go!
>
> Ross: (to Joey) Dude, **we were good**!

Does Ross mean by that that they almost managed to get out of the dinner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question can't really be answered without watching the clip (or without more description of the character's movements) because the word *good* has such a variety of meanings, and more than one of the possible meanings would fit in the context.

For instance, before watching, the clip, I assumed that the meaning would be, [2. c: Competent, Skillful](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good).  As in, *when we tried to convince them to let us leave, our performance was skillful.*

In fact, it's this definition:

> **good**
>
> 1. h *informal* : having everything desired or required : content and not wanting or needing to do anything further

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good

The meaning would have been more obvious if Ross had finished the thought he left unstated: "Dude, we were *good*...but then you kept talking and ruined our story."

Stated more plainly, Ross might have said, "Dude, we had already convinced them.  There was nothing more that needed to be said."